# How to process css with postcss inside sapper-template with rollup

Tags: rollup, postcss, svelte

Having trouble using [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss) with [sapper-template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template):

`npx degit sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup my-app`

`npm install rollup-plugin-postcss --save-dev`

install various postcss plugin

create `src/css/main.css`

add `import './css/main.css';` to the top line of `src/client.js`

*edit `rollup.config.js`

*add `postcss.config.js`

*going wrong here? I have tried several variations.

```
// rollup.config.js
...
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
...

export default {
    client: {
        input: config.client.input(),
        output: config.client.output(),
        plugins: [
            replace({
                'process.browser': true,
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
            }),
            svelte({
                dev,
                hydratable: true,
                emitCss: true
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            postcss({
                // extract: true,
                // sourceMap: true,
                plugins: [require('autoprefixer')]
            }),
...
```

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    ...
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
};
```

No real error message, once I add postcss to the plugins in the client:{} of rollup.config.js - css breaks on the site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of simply putting the `svelte` plugin config together properly. I would recommend you use `svelte-preprocess` and setup your `rollup.config.js` as follows:

```
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const preprocessOptions = {
    postcss: {
        plugins: [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
                stage: 0,
                browsers: 'last 2 versions',
                autoprefixer: { grid: true }
            }),
            ...
        ]
      }
};

...
export default {
    client: {
        plugins: [
            svelte({
                preprocess: autoPreprocess(preprocessOptions),
                dev,
                hydratable: true,
                emitCss: true
            }),
            ...
```

As you see here, you need to set the `preprocess` option of the svelte plugin.